# How to run a function in react native when you press on a picture?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to run a function on press of a picture in react native.

```
  <Image source={mysource} onPress={()=>{Alert.alert("hello")}} />
```

Am I supposed to do it like this? It doesnt work. I think I should wrap the image by button tags but I am not sure how to do it. Is there any best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to wrap inside the Touchable property like this:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {Alert.alert("hello")}}>
    <Image source={mysource} />
</TouchableHighlight>
```